# (UNITY3D) Как превратить стринговое значение в название переменной?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

В общем, допустим, что я хочу удалить некий обьект, который называется **Player1**. Как мне превратить эту строку в название переменной?

```
Rigidbody Player1;
Destroy("Player" + "1");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Destroy("Player" + "1");

`Destroy` это не про какую-то абстрактную переменную. а конкретно `GameObject`.

> в название переменной?

Вот название: `GameObject.name` оно и так `string`, ничего "превращать" не требуется.

```
if (someGameObject.name == "Player"+"1") 
    Destroy(someGameObject);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!